# how to change ajax value according to left join tables in php?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to use ajax to add a row to add a product to the invoice.

**This is my ajax code**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'php_action/fetchProductData.php',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    success:function(response) {
        $("#addRowBtn").button("reset");            

        var tr = '<tr id="row'+count+'" class="'+arrayNumber+'">'+                          
            '<td>'+
                '<div class="form-group">'+

                '<select class="form-control" name="productName[]" id="productName'+count+'" onchange="getProductData('+count+')" >'+
                    '<option value="">~~SELECT~~</option>';
                    // console.log(response);
                    $.each(response, function(index, value) {
                        tr += '<option value="'+value[0]+'">'+value[3]+value[4]+value[1]+'</option>';                           
                    });
                                                
                tr += '</select>'+
                '</div>'+
```

**and this is fetchProductData.php**

```
        <?php   
    
    require_once 'core.php';
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM product left join categories on product.categories_id = categories.categories_id 
left join brands on product.brand_id = brands.brand_id  WHERE status = 1 AND active = 1";
    $result = $connect->query($sql);
    
    $data = $result->fetch_all();
    
    $connect->close();
    
echo json_encode($data);
```

in the ajax code everything is working properly, but value[3] and value[4] are showing the **id** of the category and the brand and not the **brand name and category name** of the according to the table (Left Join is not working)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should not use `*` if you need to join 2 or more table, because sql server is gonna be confused about id field of all table. You can try this 2 ways:

- `select *, brands.id brand_id, categories.id category_id from ...`: or specify it clearly as alias
- `select *, brands.id from ...`: choose id field you want to override it, just leave that id after `*`